# How to include jquery steps plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-steps

I have been trying to run a basic jQuery steps example but an not able to do so. Is there something wrong with this code?
the jquery.steps.js plugin is in the same folder as the html doc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="jquery.steps.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$("#example-basic").steps({
headerTag: "h3",
bodyTag: "section",
transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
autoFocus: true
});


</script>

<div id="example-basic">
<h3>Keyboard</h3>
<section>
<p>Try the keyboard navigation by clicking arrow left or right!</p>
</section>
<h3>Effects</h3>
<section>
<p>Wonderful transition effects.</p>
</section>
<h3>Pager</h3>
<section>
<p>The next and previous buttons help you to navigate through your content.</p>
</section>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there an error throwing in the console or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running the code before the element is rendered on the page.

Either move the script block after the element on the page or wrap the content in [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
$(function() {  //shortcut for document ready
    $("#example-basic").steps({
        ...
    });
});
```